# Optimization problem test suites

Tags: mathematical-optimization

*Mathematica* provides nonlinear, unconstrained test problems here:

```
Needs["Optimization`UnconstrainedProblems`"]
```

and LP test problems here:

```
ExampleData["LinearProgramming"]
```

Does anyone know a good source of constrained nonlinear problems in *Mathematica* format? Also nice to have, but not essential, would be mixed integer linear and nonlinear test problems.

Comment: As an alternative, has anyone written a package for parsing GAMS files into a form that can used Mathematica's optimization functions?